# Firefox crashes when opening file . Upgraded from 14.04.4 to 16.04 lubuntu (on top of ubuntu)

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, crash

As I said in topic I have just upgraded from latest 14.04 to newest 16.04 . Some minor issues are documented like loosing mouse pointer after openning screen lock. But this is more important. Firefox crashes when one need to open file either through menu or through web form or from extension.

My default file manager is pcmanfm and it worked well in 14.04 version. I have tried to change mime tipes inode directory but it is already good. I have also tried to remove from inode the audacious but still nothing.

I have tried to remove the audacious and it lead to downgarde system from lubuntu to lxde (I have lubuntu-desktop over ubuntu). After bringing back the old lib for audacious I have succseded to bring back lubuntu-desktop. The bluetooth doesnt work neither , and that bluetooth send-file. Is there something in some prefernces to change something to bring the pcmanfm well integrated with other apps? 
Thanks.

Comment: Installing Nautilus or Thunar does not solve the problem. Also changing mime or using exo-preferred-applications doesn't solve the problem.  As said by opening file from Firefox or saving document Firefox crashes. The similiar is with the evince when tried to save the copy document it crashes.

Comment: Reinstaling lubuntu-desktop doesn't solve the problem too.

Comment: I have found system wide defaults.list on my sytem and on one it was nautilus insted of pcmanfm but after changing to pcmanfm it didn't solved the problem. Here is the list.             /etc/gnome/defaults.list
/etc/xdg/lubuntu/applications/defaults.list
/home/nik/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
/usr/share/gnome/applications/defaults.list

Comment: New clue:  (firefox:5843): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser' does not contain a key named 'date-format'

Answer (score 0):

I have to answer my own qustion because of users which will confront the same issue. I solved this situation on following way.

Firstlly it is not firefox specific but system wide.
I tried with  glib-compile-schemas and  seting XDG_DATA_DIRS to /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas but without success. But  creating a ~/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas directory, copying all schema files in here, and exporting XDG_DATA_DIRS=~/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas did the job for me. Now I have all applications like evince and other working open file dialog box without crashing the app.